# SoapClient does not send parameters

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am pulling my hair out. I have tried many different ways, but nothing works:

```
<?php

// Proxy is for Fiddler
$soap = new soapClient( 'http://testi.lemonsoft.eu:22000/CTP/lemonweb/userservices.svc?wsdl',     array(
    'proxy_host' => 'localhost',
    'proxy_port' => '8888'
)); 
try { 
    $test = new stdClass();
    $test->UserName = "foo";
    $test->Password = "bar";
    $test->CompanyDatabase = "baz";

    // This should work:
    print_r($soap->LogIn($test));

    /** The rest are alternative experiments, no avail: **/

    print_r($soap->LogIn(array($test)));

    print_r($soap->LogIn(array('parameters' => $test)));

    print_r($soap->login(array(
        'UserName' => 'foo',
        'Password' =>'bar',
        'CompanyDatabase' => 'baz'
    )));

    print_r($soap->__soapCall('LogIn', array('parameters' => $test)));

    print_r($soap->__soapCall('LogIn', array('parameters' => array(
        'UserName' => 'foo',
        'Password' =>'bar',
        'CompanyDatabase' => 'baz'
    ))));

    print_r($soap->LogIn(new SoapParam($test, "LogIn")));

    print_r($soap->LogIn(new SoapParam(array(
        'UserName' => 'foo',
        'Password' =>'bar',
        'CompanyDatabase' => 'baz'
    ), "LogIn")));

    print_r($soap->__soapCall('LogIn', array('parameters' => array(
        new SoapParam(array(
            'UserName' => 'foo',
            'Password' =>'bar',
            'CompanyDatabase' => 'baz'
        ), "LogIn")
    ))));

} catch (SoapFault $fault) { 
    print_r($fault);
}

?>
```

I captured the requests with fiddler and the response always looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:LogIn/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

as if the LogIn parameters are never sent. Does the empty ns1:LogIn tag really mean that? Can there be some instance inbetween, which I can not control, for some reason stripping the parameters? According to my understanding the method LogIn takes one parameter, which, according to the documentation, should be a PHP stdClass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
class LogInInfo{
    public $UserName = '1';
    public $Password = '2';
    public $CompanyDatabase = '3';
}

ini_set('display_error', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$client = new SoapClient('http://testi.lemonsoft.eu:22000/CTP/LemonWeb/UserServices.svc?singleWsdl', array(
        'classmap'=>array('LogInInfo'=>'LogInInfo'),
        'debug'=>true,
        'trace'=>true
    ));

try {
    $info = new LogInInfo();
    $resp = $client->LogIn($info);


} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}

print_r($client->__getLastRequest());
```

Result:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Lemonsoft.LemonsoftServiceLibrary.User" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:LogIn xsi:type="ns1:LogInInfo">
        <ns1:CompanyDatabase>3</ns1:CompanyDatabase>
        <ns1:Password>2</ns1:Password>
        <ns1:UserName>1</ns1:UserName>
    </ns2:LogIn>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: It works, but it does not make any sense why. The interface between PHP and the WSDL service isn't supposed to care about original data types because the information that travels back and forth is XML regardless. I shouldn't need to define a class for everything and then map them to the SoapClient instance. What am I not getting here?

Comment: If you look closer to the wsdl you will see that LogIn message require a parameter with specific structure. Login class is not required - it can be stdClass - but using classmap will ease your development with for example code competition in your editor :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show content of the WSDL file?

ns1:LogIn tag means that method LogIn is from ns1 namespace (defined above).

Comment: 4th line, where I make a new SoapClient: http://testi.lemonsoft.eu:22000/CTP/lemonweb/userservices.svc?wsdl

Comment: Looking on WSDL for Authservice http://testi.lemonsoft.eu:22000/CTP/LemonWeb/UserServices.svc?singleWsdl you should have a additional object inbetween : LogInInfo with fields UserName and Password.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I manage to pass the params in SOAP request from PHP is like this:

```
// __setSoapHeaders here

$listCriteriaXML = '<List xmlns="LINKHERE">
  <listCriteria>
    <ListCriterion>
      <Name>DateNeeded</Name>
      <SingleValue>' . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+120 days")) . '</SingleValue>
    </ListCriterion>
    <ListCriterion>
      <Name>limitresults</Name>
      <SingleValue>false</SingleValue>
    </ListCriterion>
  </listCriteria>
</List>';

$listCriteria = new SoapVar($listCriteriaXML, XSD_ANYXML);

$response = $client->List($listCriteria);

echo $client->__getLastRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having params not propagated to the message. Trying array, stdClass, real class, new SoapParams() ...

At the end I find out, that the SoapClient getFunctions definiton from WSDL came in the format that the params must be set separately into request method.
So, instead of this (it was also in all SOAP examples I have seen so far), which was not working:

```
$params = array("param1"=>"hello",...);
$soapClient->getMyData($params);
```

In my case, it is enough to use:

```
$soapClient->getMyData($param1, $param2, $param3);
```

You can find out simply by executing function

```
$soapClient->__getFunctions()
```

If the response is having multiple params per function, then this is the case. Response in case of multiple params per request function:

```
Array ( [0] => MyClass getMyData(date $dateFrom, date $dateTo, string $contractNumber) [1] => OtherClass otherMethod(...),...)
```